# Admin Login Page with password using MFC 6?

Tags: mfc

How do I create an Admin Login Page with password for a Visual C++ 6 application using MFC 6?

Comment: As Mark says, this is the wrong site for this question. However, this [link](http://www.functionx.com/visualc/applications/login.htm) seems like it might be a good place for you to start.

Answer (score 1):

Create a dialog box with an edit control on it. Check the box for the "Password" property so that the password will not display as it is typed in. Use the usual DDX/DDV routines to get and validate the password when the user dismisses the dialog.

Comment: Thanks's for your response but I'm entirely new to VC++ and its MFC. Can you expansiate futher; I know I have to create controls for username and password, but how do I validate the password and link to the next page or dialog?

Comment: @AbidemiKastroOni, you've come to the wrong place. This site is for answering specific questions, but you're really asking how to program in MFC - much too large a question to answer here. You'll need to look for books or tutorials.